# What exactly does Haxe export for iphone/ipads?

Tags: ios, iphone, actionscript-3, ipad, haxe

I am thinking of learning Haxe, after extensive as3 experience and some javascript/nodejs but several people have stated that haxe compiles into a swf and encapsulates it to be run on "insert platform here" making it both incompatible with some native features and with significant overhead.

I am interested in knowing about ipad/iphone specifically. Does this somehow compile into a format compatible with such apple devices? I mean does it translate to x-code then compiles it or what?

I have various clients that want cross platform versions of the same application and Haxe looks like a simple, elegant solution but since my clients are from US, Apple products are a concern to me.

My scope of projects revolves around simple apps with server services and maybe some webcam/microphone action, if this helps for an answer. Cheers.

Comment: Are you asking about haxe or openfl in particular?

Comment: Haxe. Never heard about Openfl till now. Feel free to steer me to it if its superior.

Comment: Haxe is just a programming language that can "compile" to other programming languages, openfl is a library/framework for haxe that emulates the flash API to other platforms.
When you hear that people have ported their flash game to iOS with haxe they probably used openfl.
I cannot speak for iOS, but I've used openfl for android and I can tell you that it will use the NDK (so the haxe code will be converted to c+) but it will also provide with an eclipse android project that you can compile/modify yourself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> haxe compiles into a swf and encapsulates it to be run on "insert platform here" making it both incompatible with some native features and with significant overhead.

This is a big misconception. Though as with any cross-platform tech, it's a somewhat nuanced answer.

First, know that Haxe is simply a programming language that compiles to many other language (& bitcode) targets, e.g. JavaScript, C++, PHP, python, SWF, hl, neko and others.

Compiling to C++ is the typical path when building native Android and iOS apps (and Windows and Mac apps, for that matter).  Also, Haxe is just the language. Usually a framework is used for building apps, and there are many choices -- [OpenFL](http://www.openfl.org/), or its predecessor [Haxe NME](https://github.com/haxenme/nme), or [heaps.io](https://heaps.io), or [HaxeFlixel](https://haxeflixel.com/), or [luxe](https://luxeengine.com/), or [Kha](http://kha.tech/).

Each framework is unique in paradigms and workflows, but for example, last time I used OpenFL, **it exports an XCode project with C++ code when building for iOS**. You are then expected to open and compile the project in XCode and onto your device (or for the app store), just like any other iOS app.

While using a framework is a common way to build apps with Haxe, you can roll your own, if you like, for example:

---

Compile Haxe to JavaScript, using [externs](https://haxe.org/manual/lf-externs.html) to leverage existing JS libs (e.g. here's a set of [Pixi.js externs](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi-haxe), or the built-in [jQuery externs](http://api.haxe.org/js/jquery/JQuery.html)), and develop mobile web apps with Haxe. Note: many of the above frameworks support a Haxe -> JS workflow.

---

Compile Haxe to SWF, and then use the [Adobe AIR SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html) to package your app as a native iOS / Android app.  This avoids XCode and is possible from Linux and Windows (where compiling an XCode project is not). Perhaps this flow is what those other people were talking about.

---

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I will think of you fondly, on my death bed.

Comment: If you're a mobile app developer, I imagine that could be all too soon.  =)

Comment: I think you are confusing C and C++, Haxe is translated to C++ not C when using openfl, the C target for haxe is still a work in progress.

Comment: Thanks @lordkryss, updated to C++.  For those of us who don't use those native languages much, we tend to confuse them.

Comment: Just to add to the fun, you can also use Haxe to target JS on iPad.  This is the approach taken by [Flambe](https://github.com/aduros/flambe) and has decent performance, I've played some finished games with it and was relatively impressed with performance etc...